# How to use for cycle inside xls

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

I have a very long String, that I want to display with xslt.
The xslt code fragment is this:

```
<xsl:template match="report:rmessagewithbutton">
    <h2>Running and terminated requests</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- <xsl:for-each select="rmessagewithbutton"> + -->
                <message>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </message>
                <!-- </xsl:for-each> -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Stop Request" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I generate the xml with java by the following methods:

```
public static void generateOutputWithButton(final ContentHandler contentHandler,  final String msg)  throws SAXException{
    contentHandler.startElement(REPORT_NS, "rmessagewithbutton", "report:rmessagewithbutton",  SAXHelper.NO_ATTR);
    generateIWithButton(contentHandler, msg);
    contentHandler.endElement(REPORT_NS, "rmessagewithbutton", "report:rmessagewithbutton");        
}
public static void generateIWithButton(final ContentHandler contentHandler, final String text) throws SAXException {    
    contentHandler.startElement(I18nTransformer.I18N_NAMESPACE_URI, I18nTransformer.I18N_TEXT_ELEMENT, FormsConstants.I18N_PREFIX_COLON + I18nTransformer.I18N_TEXT_ELEMENT, SAXHelper.NO_ATTR);
    SAXHelper.toSAX(contentHandler, text);
    contentHandler.endElement(I18nTransformer.I18N_NAMESPACE_URI, I18nTransformer.I18N_TEXT_ELEMENT, FormsConstants.I18N_PREFIX_COLON + I18nTransformer.I18N_TEXT_ELEMENT);
}
```

That displays the very long String in one piece. If I want the String to be displayed line by line then I have to call the generateOutputWithButton() method form inside a cycle.
Something like this:

```
for (String l : StringUtils.split(message, "\n")) {
ReportGeneratorHelper.generateOutputWithButton(contentHandler, l);
 }
```

This solution however has an unwanted side-effect. It displays *everything*, the whole table many times. So I need to remove the cycle from the Java code, and put it to the xsl. But I am not familiar with the syntax, and I am not sure on which should I iterate over..
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can provide a sample (small) source XML document and the wanted result from the transformation?

Comment: thank you I have found a solution in the meantime

Comment: pr123, I see, but I'd recommend to use a pure XSLT solution -- no need for Java code at all.

Comment: thanks, but the architecture of our application demands the use of Java

Comment: @p123 Well, if this is so, then why are you using XSLT and asking an XSLT question? Just write everything in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: a for cycle can remain in the java code, but applied only to the subelements.

```
public static void generateOutputWithButton(final ContentHandler contentHandler,  final String msg)  throws SAXException{

        contentHandler.startElement(REPORT_NS, "rmessagewithbutton", "report:rmessagewithbutton",  SAXHelper.NO_ATTR);
         for (String l : StringUtils.split(msg, "\n")) {
                contentHandler.startElement(REPORT_NS, "subelement", "report:subelement",  SAXHelper.NO_ATTR);
                generateIWithButton(contentHandler, l);
                contentHandler.endElement(REPORT_NS, "subelement", "report:subelement");        
         }
        contentHandler.endElement(REPORT_NS, "rmessagewithbutton", "report:rmessagewithbutton");        
    }



<xsl:template match="report:rmessagewithbutton">
    <h2>Running and terminated requests</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="report:subelement"/>
    </table>
```

```
<xsl:template match="report:subelement">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <message>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </message>
                </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Stop Request" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</xsl:template>
```